# Emacs like line navigation in sublime text 3?

Tags: emacs, ide, sublimetext2, text-editor, emacs23

I have been using Emacs from past few months and I like its line navigation feature a lot as it does't need you to use arrow keys.

Emacs Line Navigation:

```
C-p : go to previous line
C-n : go to next line
C-f : go forward one character
C-b : go backward one character
```

Is there anyway I can use this in sublime text 3 also? 
I have read in some blogs that some people did this but I cant find instructions how to do it.

Comment: Don't forget `C-a` and `C-e` ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [sublemacspro](https://github.com/grundprinzip/sublemacspro) project seems to provide what you want.

Comment: If you don't want all of the emacs functionality, you can take the relevant keybindings from the `Default.sublime-keymap` file on the plugin, and put them in your User keybindings.

Comment: Just copy & paste the key-bindings of your choice into the Preferences -> keybindings from the following file: https://github.com/grundprinzip/sublemacspro/blob/master/Default.sublime-keymap

Comment: @Datageek, here's a link to the section for  "Motion Commands": https://github.com/sublime-emacs/sublemacspro/blob/d129e116c806235b56ab7575df470eb852ebc36e/Default.sublime-keymap#L66